# Issue with WSO2 BAM: Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

In Centos OS I deployed a BAM 2.0.1 server with the default config.
After that I configure the AS and ESB toolbox I configure my AS and ESB server to use this BAM.

when I restart the BAM server I started to see this error in console.:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,031]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script esb_stats_903. [Thu Dec 06 12:06:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,037]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script service_stats_263. [Thu Dec 06 12:06:00 CST 2012] {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,720] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:933)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraManager.openConnection(CassandraManager.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler.preCreateTable(CassandraStorageHandler.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:540)
        ... 16 more
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,720] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:933)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraManager.openConnection(CassandraManager.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler.preCreateTable(CassandraStorageHandler.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:540)
        ... 16 more
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,721] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,721] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,724] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,727] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : esb_stats_903 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,726] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:933)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraManager.openConnection(CassandraManager.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler.preCreateTable(CassandraStorageHandler.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:540)
        ... 16 more
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,726] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:933)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:187)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Unable to connect to the server org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraException: unable to connect to server)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraManager.openConnection(CassandraManager.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler.preCreateTable(CassandraStorageHandler.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:540)
        ... 16 more
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,734] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,734] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,735] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-12-06 12:06:00,736] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : service_stats_263 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u change the port offset in BAM? If so Hive scripts would require a modification in cassandra port parameter.

Comment: as I see this is a random error. After a while I don´t see it anymore :-D by the way I do not changed anything in the config files.